# How SSAS cube's partitions will point to different fact tables

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssas

I am creating a cube, where in one fact-view I am fetching data for all dates, and that data is going to a partition called historical. Now I need to create one more partition that will contain daily data, but that daily data will not come from the same fact-view, for that I have created another fact-subset-view. I am not able to picturise, what all the steps I should follow to make two partitions from two different fact tables.
At the end if the processing I need to merge daily partition to historical one.
Can anyone enlighten me on this side please.

Comment: Add partitions and use query binding (rather than DSV tables) for the partition query.

Comment: Why can't you combine both fact-views in a single view and use that as the source of the measure group?